# Disable apostrophe t space Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

When I type in a comment (JavaDoc or line comment) IntelliJ automatically inserts a tag when I type something like `// don't` and I hit the spacebar after the `'t` I see `// don'< ></>` with my cursor ready to type in the first tag. Does anyone know how to disable this behavior? I've tried google searching and searching through the settings with no avail. I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 13.0.1 community edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a live template is being activated via the sequence <kbd>t</kbd><kbd>space</kbd>, although to the best of my knowledge this is not a default one. Go to *File > Settings > [IDE Settings] > Live Templates*. Search for a template that has `t` as its shortcut and inserts tags. Either delete it, or change its activation from <kbd>space</kbd> to <kbd>tab</kbd> (in the lower right). You may also want to check (and possibly change) the "default expand with" setting at the top.